# i work with snmp in spring boot project and i get this error message when i enter the route in the controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, snmp4j

**Controller**

```
    import PFEproject.APIs.services.SNMPManager;


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/snmp")

    public class snmptestC {

        @GetMapping
        public void ResponseEntity()throws Exception {

            SNMPManager client = new SNMPManager("udp:127.0.0.1/161");
            client.start();
            String sysDescr = client.getAsString(new OID(".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2"));
            System.out.println(sysDescr);

        }
      }

**snmpManager class**

    import org.snmp4j.*;
public class SNMPManager {
    private Snmp snmp = null;
    private String address = null;

    public SNMPManager(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void start() throws IOException {
        TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
        snmp = new Snmp(transport);
        transport.listen();

    }

    public ResponseEvent get(OID oids[]) throws IOException {
        PDU pdu = new PDU();
        for (OID oid : oids) {
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(oid));
        }
        pdu.setType(PDU.GET);
        ResponseEvent event = snmp.send(pdu, getTarget(), null);
        if(event != null) {
            return event;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("GET timed out");
    }
    public String getAsString(OID oid) throws IOException {

        ResponseEvent event = get(new OID[] { oid });

        return event.getResponse().get(0).getVariable().toString();

    }
    private Target getTarget() {
        Address targetAddress = GenericAddress.parse(address);
        CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
        target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
        target.setAddress(targetAddress);
        target.setRetries(2);
        target.setTimeout(1500);
        target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
        return target;
    }

}
```

**error message**

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   org/snmp4j/transport/DefaultUdpTransportMapping has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/snmp4j/transport/DefaultUdpTransportMapping has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: Run with a later version of Java?

Comment: your JRE version is not supported by the version of dependency you are using. Which JRE version are you using?

Comment: im using java 8 should i install java 9 ?

Answer (score 0):

The current JRE doesn't support the given class file version of the file `org/snmp4j/transport/DefaultUdpTransportMapping`.

You can either update your JDK/JRE to version supported or use the version of the library providing this class `org/snmp4j/transport/DefaultUdpTransportMapping`, supported by JAVA 8.

From SMNP4j [website](https://www.snmp4j.org/),

> SNMP4J 3.1.0, SNMP4J-Agent 3.2.0, and SNMP4J-AgentX 3.0.0 or later require Java SE 9 or later runtime. SNMP4J-SMI and SNMP4J-SMI-PRO require Java 8 or later compiler and runtime.

In the case of inhouse libraries, they can be recompiled and used with the java version you are using, if they are compatible.

Class file version 53.0 is supported by Java 9 and above.